# Is there a way to use pre-existing JSP Tag libraries within the Lift framework (e.g. via snippets)?

Tags: jsp, scala, tags, code-snippets, lift

I'm fairly new to Lift/Scala but like the ideas of less code writing and function passing etc.

I've had a brief look at the Lift web framework but was wondering if it is at all possible to leverage pre-existing JSP Tag libraries, ideally while being able to still place/mix with Lift's snippet tags?

As Scala is able to utilise normal Java libraries, it would seem a shame to not, directly, be able to use JSP Tags within Lift, in some guise.

JFYI, I am mainly considering the use of Apache's Reusable Dialog Components:

http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/rdc-doc/intro.html

for VoiceXML markup.

Cheers

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to do that - I have a feeling you're going to get incredibly frustrated with the entire process, give up, and just use some Java frameworks + libs instead of Lift.

In fact, that might be your best approach.

Comment: I kind of feared someone might say this :-< . Although I do want to use the Tag lib/Scala, I was actually fishing to see whether this non-usage of JSP libraries is an oversight on Lift's part? Scala offers JVM compatibility, but should we be discarding large chunks of perfectly good [JSP Tag lib] code?

Also, I'd like to add that I'm not solely concerned with Lift as a Scala web framework (there are slinky/sweet/scalaz etc.) but just discerning whether JSP Tags on Scala are at all possible (without having to develop wrapper code).

Thanks

Rich

Comment: They are possible - checkout the scalate framework:  http://scalate.fusesource.org/